# use button to pass td data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I want to give the user the ability to select.  I added an button, value="Update", to the beginning of the row, and assigned an onclick value.  My problem is that I want to send other items(in td>s on the same row) from the row to the function called by the button.

How do I get the information from the row the button is on?  I would like to pass the "Name" and "Last Update Time" to the function the button calls.  I tried using the following:

```
$("#Report input[name=btn_id]").closest('td').attr('text')
```

but it returns "undefined," which I am not surprised by, as I think this is due to it not knowing what row of the table to pull from.

Here is a view of the table: [image]
Here is the code behind the table:

```
<table align="center" border="1" class="report" id="report">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="75">Update</th>
        <th width="500">Name</th>
        <th width="50">Info</th>
        <th width="100">location</th>
        <th width="100">Last Update Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="parent" id="other_app">
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update" onclick="UpdateRec(d1)">
        </td>
        <td name="App_Name">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">None</td>
        <td align="center">Desktop</td>
        <td align="center">2014-06-30 18:22:39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="other_app">
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update" onclick="UpdateAppRec(d1)">
        </td>
        <td name="App_Name">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">None</td>
        <td align="center">Server</td>
        <td align="center">2014-03-30 16:20:15</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `attr('text')` won't work. you could use `.text()`. You can also use `$(this)` instead of using the selector, because the value of `this` will be the button context.

Comment: How about you just add them as parameter of the javascript function the button calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embrace the power of **this**.

Using:

```
onclick="UpdateRec(this)"
```

..in your function:

```
function UpdateRec(el) {
   var targetRow = $(el).parents('tr')
   ...
}
```

Using *this* passes a reference to the clicked element. You can then use jQuery to select the parent table row. From there you can use .find() to select anything in that row.

Another way to do this would be to use HTML5 data- attributes on this button itself:

```
<input type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update" onclick="UpdateRec(d1)" data-appName="something" />
```

In the same function you can then use `$(el).data('appName')` to get the value directly without looking up values in other DOM elements.

Comment: This worked great.  I did not have to modify much code for this and you also provided a suitable means of including the "d1" I referenced.  I was unaware of the "data-" option, this was very enlightening and I will use this.  I marked the item  under this for a one up as well.  I used the code provided to get me the details from the TDs, which saved time as I did not want to add the data in multiple places.  The original table is built via javascript and contains almost 9K rows, including the children rows, did not want to increase build time.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add a click listener on all your buttons using event delegation
$('#Report').click(onUpdateButtonClicked, 'input[name=btn_id]');

function onUpdateButtonClicked() {
    var rowValues = $(this)
        .parent() //select parent td
        .nextAll() //select all next siblings of that parent td
        .map(function () { //loop through the tds, collecting their text value
            return $(this).text();
        }).get(); //return the result as an array

    //do what you want with rowValues
}
```

Comment: I tried this and could not get it to work.  It was as if the listener was not catching the call.  I inserted it in the do ready section as well as just before the function to no avail. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use common class for all update buttons with common click event handler.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwet6z6x/

**HTML:**

```
<table align="center" border="1" class="report" id="report">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="75">Update</th>
        <th width="500">Name</th>
        <th width="50">Info</th>
        <th width="100">location</th>
        <th width="100">Last Update Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="parent" id="other_app">
        <td align="center">
            <input class="updateBtn" type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update">
        </td>
        <td name="App_Name">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">None</td>
        <td align="center">Desktop</td>
        <td align="center">2014-06-30 18:22:39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="other_app">
        <td align="center">
            <input class="updateBtn" type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update">
        </td>
        <td name="App_Name">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">None</td>
        <td align="center">Server</td>
        <td align="center">2014-03-30 16:20:15</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".updateBtn").click(function(){
    var name =  $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(1).html()
    var time =  $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(4).html()
    alert (name);
    alert (time);
})
```

Comment: This and the code above worked great together.  The ability to get the 'td' information was very useful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follow : http://jsfiddle.net/Lk91cpup/2/

```
<table> 
<tr id="row_1">
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="btn_row_1" class="btn" value="Update">
    </td>
    <td id="text_row_1">Test1</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>Desktop</td>
    <td >2014-06-30 18:22:39</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_2">
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="btn_row_2" class="btn" value="Update">
    </td>
    <td id="text_row_2">Test2</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>Server</td>
    <td>2014-03-30 16:20:15</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

And Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn").click(function(){

        var id = this.id.substring(this.id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);

        alert($("#text_row_" + id).text());

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="parent" id="other_app">
    <td align="center">
        <input type="button" name="btn_id" value="Update" onclick="UpdateRec(d1, 'Test1', 'None',  'Desktop', '2014-06-30')">
    </td>
    <td name="App_Name">Test1</td>
    <td align="center">None</td>
    <td align="center">Desktop</td>
    <td align="center">2014-06-30 18:22:39</td>
</tr>
```

Since you have already written a javascript function call why not just include the things you need right?

This is simplier but not the best practise.